# Big query, how to split TIMESTAMP data type column

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to split a column that contains TIMESTAMP data type into two separate columns DATE and TIME. Because I am trying to use WHERE clause with condition where time is MORE THAN 2MINUTES in my case : WHERE ride_length > to_timestamp'00:02:00' and is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract) to get date, time and minutes from a timestamp.

Example:

```sql
WITH table1 AS 
(
  SELECT TIMESTAMP("2022-06-27 10:00:00") AS dt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP("2022-06-27 12:03:00") AS dt
)

SELECT
EXTRACT(DATE FROM dt) AS date,
EXTRACT(TIME FROM dt) AS time
FROM table1
WHERE EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM dt) > 2
```

Comment: (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP("2022-06-27 10:00:00") AS dt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP("2022-06-27 12:03:00") AS dt
)  I assume this is where I input a range like between this and that date?

Comment: I have almost 5.5 mil rows so I need to apply condition for the whole data set, how can I do this?

Comment: No, the [WITH clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause) is like creating a temporary table, I just used it to show you how the query works! Please make yourself familiar with the basics of BQ and SQL. You can use your table instead of `table1` in my code example.